# Android Layout: cannot see the children over the parent

Tags: android, layout, view, parent, children

I have the Layouts as you can see in the picture (sorry I cannot post them normally yet):
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/28640502/Unbenannt.bmp

However, when I execute the app I can only see the camera preview and not the text nor the SeekBar. I know they work, because when I reduce the size of the camera I can see them and interact, but if I want the camera to be like background and then the children over it, it doesn't work.

I have been checking a lot of threads with similar problems but I don't find the solution:
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6759279/how-to-bring-view-on-front-of-everything), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5380374/android-how-to-make-a-child-view-overlap-the-parent), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6759036/how-to-send-view-to-back-how-to-control-the-z-order-programmatically)... Any idea? Thanks a lot!

Here is my xml code just in case:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.55"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="fill">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/show_height"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5sp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10sp"
                android:layout_weight="0.12"
                android:text="H" />

            <SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/select_height"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_margin="5sp"
                android:layout_weight="0.91" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/show_distance"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.06"
                android:text="Dist" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to input both of your layouts in relative layout for example

```
<LL>
  <RL>
    <FL>
    </FL>
    <LL>
    </LL>
  </RL>
</LL>
```

this is hapenning because of overlaiyng of LL by FL

Comment: I mean, why in a RL the overlap doesn't occur and when I have tried with LL or making children of the FL it fails?

Comment: because you use camera content in FL, but if you will not init you RL with any class youll see all  inner layouts

Comment: Oh, so the "trick" is that RL is not initialized. I get it.
And why didn´t it work when both RL and LL were children of the first LL, like this:

<LL> //
    <FL>
    </FL>
    <LL>
    </LL> //
</LL>
? (sorry I cannot coment in different lines to order it so I put // instead)

Comment: No the trik was that if RL initialised it will override all inner Layouts, in that case that i suggest you Rl initialised by itself LL by itself. And nothing is overrided (but overlaped)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the bringToFront() method of the View class.

```
SeekBar seeker = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.select_height);
seeker.bringToFront();
```

Alernatively you could use the sendToBack() function to put a view behind other views.

Also remember that a view's z-index is determined by the order in which the view is declared in the xml layout file.

I'd also suggest changing the camera preview layout and it's first child layout to be siblings. The one added last in the xml file will be on top.